# How to count specific elements inside tuples after using Counter() - Python

Tags: python, combinations, counter, data-analysis

I would kindly ask you to help me to clarify a doubt about Data Analysis with `Python`.

I am working on a `DataFrame` that displays sales data from a fictional company. In order to identify which pairs of products are most often sold together, I created a column named 'Grouped', which groups the products that were registered with the same 'Order ID' (each item is separated by a comma).

After that, I used `Counter()` from `collections` and `combinations` from `itertools` to count how many times each pair appeared in the 'Grouped' column. Please, check the following code:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

count_pairs=Counter()

for row in df['Grouped']:
    
    row_list=row.split(',')
    count_pairs.update(Counter(combinations(row_list,2))) # I want to count pairs of two
    
count_pairs.most_common(5)
```

This is the output that was generated:

```
[(('iPhone', 'Lightning Charging Cable'), 1004),
 (('Google Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 987),
 (('iPhone', 'Wired Headphones'), 447),
 (('Google Phone', 'Wired Headphones'), 414),
 (('Vareebadd Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 361)]
```

Now, I want to identify what are the products that appear the most in this list, that is, how many times each item appears in the available pairs.

I tried to analyze them individually with the following code:

```
['Lightning Charging Cable' in x for x in count_pairs].count(True) #output = 37
```

However, I want to create "a list or a series" and sort the results by the number of times each item appears in the available pairs.

Do you know a way to solve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Additional info:

As some of you used the top-five pairs (count_pairs.most_common(5)) to solve this problem, I would like to inform that I will need to count the elements based on a 'Counter object', which is 'count_pairs':

```
count_pairs
```

The summarized output of 'count_pairs' is:

```
Counter({('Google Phone', 'Wired Headphones'): 414,
         ('Google Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'): 987,
         ('Bose SoundSport Headphones', 'Bose SoundSport Headphones'): 27,
         ('AAA Batteries (4-pack)', 'Google Phone'): 11,
         ('Lightning Charging Cable', 'USB-C Charging Cable'): 58,....}) 
#the original output has 313 pairs
```

Comment: To double check what you're asking for, you want to count the number of pairs each item is in, rather than the number of rows of your original data it was in? For example, if the top-five you showed us was the whole count, you'd expect `'iPhone'` to come up with a count of 2, not something related to 1004 and 447?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I want to count the number of pairs each item is in. So,  as you said, if the top-five I showed you was the whole count, I would expect 'iPhone' to come up with a count of 2. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully properly address the issue you added to your question, that of operating on the original `count_pairs` structure.

Comment: @CryptoFool This is what I needed! I just included the following code to sort the ouput based on the n° of pairs each item is in: df.sort_values(1, ascending=False). Thank you very much!

Comment: @CryptoFool Today, I realized that the outputs are different in the following situations: 1) when I use '['Lightning Charging Cable' in x for x in count_pairs].count(True)', the output is 37. 2) When I use your solution, the output indicates that the 'Lightning Charging Cable' is in 19 pairs only. I will try to understand this discrepancy. Maybe I can convert the pairs into a string and search for the products using regex. If the result is 19, your solution is correct. In case you are interested, the dataset I'm using can be found at: https://github.com/KeithGalli/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do this:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

data = [(('iPhone', 'Lightning Charging Cable'), 1004),
 (('Google Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 987),
 (('iPhone', 'Wired Headphones'), 447),
 (('Google Phone', 'Wired Headphones'), 414),
 (('Vareebadd Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 361)]

df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(Counter([x[0][1] for x in data]).items(), key= lambda x : x[1]))
```

To apply the same transformation to the original `count_pairs` data structure, just remove the `[0]` from `x[0][1]`, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted(Counter([x[1] for x in count_pairs]).items(), key= lambda x : x[1]))
```

The effective difference between the two structures is that `data` has an extra outer `list` that doesn't exist in `count_pairs`.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but it is not working. I only replaced 'data' for 'count_pairs' (you can check this 'object'  in my code). Count_pairs it is a 'Counter object'. When I tried to use your solution, the output was a dataframe with a bunch of random numbers on the right column and random letters and numbers in the column on the left. I am trying to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: It must be that `count_pairs` and `count_pairs.most_common(5)` have different structures.  I admit that I made the assumption, quite possibly incorrectly, that the two would have the same structure, one just being a proper subset of the other.  I would need to have a way to construct `df['Grouped']` to be able to play with what you're working with.

Comment: try to change the following and run the code

count_pairs=Counter() to count_pairs()=Counter

then where ever you used count_pairs, try using count_pairs()

like count_pairs.update to count_pairs().update

Comment: @KumarShivamRay I tried to do this, but I received the following message: 'SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call'

Comment: @CryptoFool Now, it worked properly! I just added the following code in order to sort the ouput based on the n° of pairs each item is in: df.sort_values(1, ascending=False). Thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be your answer, if not do let me know

```
import pandas as pd
datas = [(('iPhone', 'Lightning Charging Cable'), 1004),
        (('Google Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 987),
        (('iPhone', 'Wired Headphones'), 447),
        (('Google Phone', 'Wired Headphones'), 414),
        (('Vareebadd Phone', 'USB-C Charging Cable'), 361)]
count = {}
for data in datas:
    if data[0][1] in list(count):
        count[data[0][1]] = count[data[0][1]][0] + 1
    else:
        count[data[0][1]] = [1]
pd.DataFrame(count).transpose().sort_values(0, ascending = True)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It looks like a pretty good solution to me. However, I am receiving a TypeError message: 'int' object is not subscriptable. I am trying to figure it out why this is happening. I only substituted 'datas' for 'count_pairs', which is a Counter 'object'. Do you know how I could solve this? Thank you very much for your help!